# Change wieght of RadioButtons with animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-layout-weight, android-radiobutton

I have the below code. I want to change the weight of radio buttons when a user clicks on this. I mean, when a user selects a radio button, change the weight of that to 2 and the weight of not selected radio button change to 1 and reverse. (the weight Sum of the radio group is 3). When I select the left side radio button, first change the size and then changed color. I want when a user selects the left radio button, it pushes from left to right not suddenly change the size.

XML code:

```
<RadioGroup
        android:checkedButton="@+id/onTimeRadioButton"
        android:id="@+id/checkToggle"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rb_drawable"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/groupRadioButton"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_widget_background"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:onClick="onRadioBttonClicked"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="groupCheck"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:onClick="onRadioBttonClicked"
            android:id="@+id/onTimeRadioButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_widget_background"
            android:button="@null"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="onTimeCheck"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

Java code:

```
 public void onRadioBttonClicked(View view){
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.groupRadioButton:
            if(checked){
                ViewWeightAnimationWrapper animationWrapper = new ViewWeightAnimationWrapper(groupRadioBtn);
                ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(animationWrapper,
                        "weight",
                        animationWrapper.getWeight(),
                        2);
                anim.setDuration(500);
                anim.start();
                ViewWeightAnimationWrapper animationWrapper2 = new ViewWeightAnimationWrapper(onTimeRadioBtn);
                animationWrapper2.getWeight();
                animationWrapper2.setWeight(1);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.onTimeRadioButton:
            if(checked){
                if(checked){
                    ViewWeightAnimationWrapper animationWrapper = new ViewWeightAnimationWrapper(onTimeRadioBtn);
                    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(animationWrapper,
                            "weight",
                            animationWrapper.getWeight(),
                            2);
                    anim.setDuration(500);
                    anim.start();
                    ViewWeightAnimationWrapper animationWrapper2 = new ViewWeightAnimationWrapper(groupRadioBtn);
                    animationWrapper2.setWeight(1);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
 public class ViewWeightAnimationWrapper {
    private View view;

    public ViewWeightAnimationWrapper(View view) {
        if (view.getLayoutParams() instanceof LinearLayout.LayoutParams) {
            this.view = view;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The view should have LinearLayout as parent");
        }
    }

    public void setWeight(float weight) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        params.weight = weight;
        view.getParent().requestLayout();
    }

    public float getWeight() {
        float test=((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).weight;
        return test;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to just change weight programaticaly  in `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`
and before that add line:

```
 TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(yourRootLinearLayout, new ChangeBounds());
```

Comment: I checked and my problem didn't solve. @Antonis Radz

Comment: it should work if you going to use correct `rootScene` and correct `transition`